# Include statement in UWP Manifest file

Tags: uwp, manifest

I have a UWP app and I need to write a prominent statement anywhere in the Metadata that the app does not support Windows 10 S.

Can you please let me know inside which tag I should write this statement ?

Comment: Hi, Do you have any special reasons for not supporting Windows 10 S? In principle, UWP applications built with WinRT can run directly on Windows 10 S

Comment: I have converted my desktop app to msix package using msix packaging tool. I have submitted the app to windows app store and I got the feedback that the app is crashing on windows 10 S and it is working fine on windows 10 syatems. My app is using cefsharp library ie. chromium browser and I guess windows 10 S is not supporting Chromium Web browser.

Comment: I read a blog which says : Windows 10 S will be limited to Microsoft’s Edge browser until other browser makers, including Firefox, Opera and Google make their browsers available through the Windows Store.

Comment: If you plan to submit your app to the Microsoft Store, you must support Windows 10 S, which means you have to test the code. For how to do this, please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-test-windows-s). If you need Chromium, you can use the [WebView2](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2019/06/18/building-hybrid-applications-with-the-webview2-developer-preview/#TQ3BjLPkJG0DgVgV.97)

Comment: Ok I'll debug in windows 10 S mode. Well how to add the above statement in manifest file (Inside which tag), if in case the app is not able to support windows 10 S ?

Answer (score 2):

The information is not added to the AppX Manifest, but to the Store metadata.

For example, in the description of your app you can say that it doesn't support "S" Mode.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a field in the app list that you need.

You can open `Package.appxmanifest` with code, change `TargetDeviceFamily`

```xml
<Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />
</Dependencies>
```

More about the `TargetDeviceFamily`, please see this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-targetdevicefamily).

This doesn't mean you can help your app pass the store's review. Anyway, supporting Windows 10 S is something you must consider.

Best regards.